# Replacing several strings in a file in one go

Tags: sed, find-and-replace, perl

Suppose I want to replace all AAA with BBB and all BBB with AAA in a text file.

The thing which looks an obvious solution (in Perl or in Sed) is:

> s/AAA/BBB/g; s/BBB/AAA/g;

But this does not work because it could after replacing AAA with BBB replace it back with AAA.

What solutions for this problem exist?

Maybe you may provide some Perl (or Python or whatever) code?

Comment: Related: [Replace multiple strings in a single pass](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137926/23408) and [Cleanly swap all occurrences of two strings using sed](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21061/23408) (on our Unix&Linux site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I've found a module which does this:

> perl -MReplaceMultiple -e 'print replace_multiple({"AAA"=>"BBB", "BBB"=>"AAA"}, "AAABBB"), "\n";'

ReplaceMultiple.pm:

```
package ReplaceMultiple;

use strict;
use warnings;

our (@ISA, @EXPORT);
require Exporter; @ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(replace_multiple_inplace replace_multiple);

sub replace_multiple_inplace {
  my ($hash, $str_ref) = @_;
  my $obj = ReplaceMultiple->new($hash);
  return $obj->apply_inplace($str_ref);
}

sub replace_multiple {
  my ($hash, $str) = @_;
  my $obj = ReplaceMultiple->new($hash);
  return $obj->apply($str);
}

sub new {
  my ($class, $hash) = @_;
  my $re_str = "(" . (join '|', map { "\Q$_\E" } keys %$hash) . ")";
  my $self = bless {HASH=>$hash, RE=>qr/$re_str/}, $class;
  return $self;
}

sub apply_inplace {
  my ($self, $str_ref) = @_;
  $$str_ref =~ s/$self->{RE}/$self->{HASH}{$1}/g;
  return $$str_ref;
}

sub apply {
  my ($self, $str) = @_;
  my $str2 = $str;
  return $self->apply_inplace(\$str2);
}

1;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, you can use the `/e` flag to **e**valuate code in the replacement part of a substitution:

```
s/(AAA|BBB)/'AAA' eq $1 ? 'BBB' : AAA/ge
```

Explanation:

- `(AAA|BBB)` matches AAA or BBB and saves the matching string in $1.
- `condition ? true : false` is the "ternary operator". It it returns the "true" value if the "condition" is true, the "false" otherwise. So, in this case, it returns the string to use for replacement.
- `/ge` means "globally", i.e. not just once per line, and "eval", i.e. understands the replacement part as code to run.